# Standard way to pass jQuery references to callbacks or plugins

Tags: javascript, scope, jquery-callback

What is the recommended way to pass cached jQuery references, e.g. `$domContainer` in `var $domContainer = $('#container');` to functions as a callback if the functions are defined before and outside of `$(document).ready()`?

Example:

```
<script src="/plugins.js"></script>
```

In this external file of re-usable functions

```
function rowAction ( event ) { // how do I get context here?

  // how can I access $domTable and $domFilters
  // I can access $(event.target) and traverse the dom
  // back to $domTable, but $domTable is not defined
  // in the external file, although a reference is cached
  // in the local scope of $(document).ready();
  // likewise, $domTable could be accessed through event.delegateTarget
  // however, how can I pass $domFilters, and other vars?

}
```

In the main script

```
<script src="/scripts.js"></script>
```

The standard document ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Cached References
    var $domFilters = $('#form .filter'), // more than 1 reference returned
        $domTable   = $('#results');      // 1 reference returned

    $domTable.on('click','.menu',rowAction);// reference function in plugins.js
    // how do I pass $domFilters to rowAction to avoid dom lookups?
    // I could pass $domFilters to a plugin like $(...).plugin({f:$domFilters});
    // if it had optional arguments, but if it's not a plugin, what's the
    // equivalent way to do it?
});
```

Would the way to approach this be to use an inline function to wrap the callback function name?

Any pointers to a standard practice would be welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to access $domTable you can use the [event.delegateTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) property of the  event object without having to traverse the dom. You will have to wrap it in a jQuery object though.

**Edit**

A standard way of passing the context and extra properties to an external function would be to use [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) jQuery has it's own wrapper for that behaviour also called [proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

In your example with `$domTable` the context is already passed through as the target of the selector so everything you need would be available to you.

In your `$domFilters` example there is no event object to pass as the context since event are mapped to actual events in the dom and all you have there is a collection so you couldn't use that function since it relies on the event object.

If I was calling another function though from a collection whilst passing the context I would use something like this.

```js
$domFilters = $('#form .filter');
$domFilters.each(function(){

    // Call the external function passing the jQuery wrapped item
    // as the context.
    externalFunction.call($(this));

});


// Your external function
function externalFunction(){

// 'this' would now refer to the context passed in call.
// i.e your $(.filter) item.

}
```

Your utility function has to be designed to be able to handle whatever is passed to it as context plus any additional arguments though.

Comment: Hi James, in this specific case, `event.delegateTarget` is the perfect answer, but in general, how would you go about passing additional cached variables. I used a bad example as jQuery already has a direct reference in this case (which I didn't know about), but I was thinking more generically if I had other cached variables, which is often the case.  I'll update the question with a more relevant context.

Comment: Hi James, in this case, we aren't acting on $domFilters, but we need it available to pass to referenced external function.  So, for example, $domFilters would contain references to objects with values we want to read in the external function.  What we want to do, though, is pass the reference to the external function when needed.  .each() wouldn't do that, here since the call should happen on the event.

Comment: Is your external function set up to handle the collection? You only have an event argument and unless it is accessing the arguments arraytype e.g `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);` within that then you can do nothing with the additional arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a modular approach by defining a NameSpace. Then you won't have to use ready.

```
//These four will be open
var objects, handlers, bindings,
NameSpace = {

    //This is where you cache references
    objects: {
        domcontainer: $('.domcontainer')
    },

    //Do the events to handlers bindings
    bindings: function(){
        domcontainer.on('click', handlers.clickCallback)
    }

    //The actual handlers
    handlers: {
        clickCallback: function(e){
            //Do something
        }
    },

    //Initial things
    init: function(){
        objects = this.objects;
        handlers = this.handlers;

        //This will start the handler binding.
        this.bindings();
    }
};

$(function () {
NameSpace.init();  
});
```

If you are adding objects on the fly, then inside objects you can add references as functions that return the actual object reference. Whenever you need to refer an object, it will be available already hence avoiding DOM look up.

Comment: Hi Rutwick, I'm trying to avoid adding global variables.

Comment: Like the open 3 at the top?

Comment: yes.  Ideally, we'd not want to add any vars outside the document.ready, and, in my simplified case above, you'd be looking for a way to pass it, perhaps as an object or array containing references or as a function that returns the variables or an object containing the references.